# pack specific dependencies into a jar

Tags: java, maven, hadoop

I have a project with lots of hadoop dependencies and org.json dependencies as well.
I want to pack the org.json dependency only into the jar, because the packing the hadoop dependencies will cause conflicts. I'm using Packaging=Jar, and using a fat jar is not suited in my case. Is there a way to package only the org.json dependencies? My pom.xml dependencies section:

```
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-auth</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.10</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSON Parser dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Log4J dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Comment: Would <optional>true<optional> work for you?

Comment: put <optional> where? and what is it supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question, maybe this is what Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen meant:
for all dependencies I don't want to be packeged add provided. Example:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

and package it as a fat jar:

```
            <!-- Maven Assembly Plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- get all project dependencies -->
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <!-- MainClass in mainfest make a executable jar -->
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.myorg.MyAppMain</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>

            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

**Edit:**
By adding provided the runtime dependencies are also excluded from the classpath, and thus the project can't run on my IDE.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the maven-shade-plugin and specify in loving detail what goes and what doesn't; you don't have to rename anything when using shade if you don't want to.

Comment: could you please show a usage example? I've tried to white list my desired dependencies, or black list the undesired ones, but the Uber-Jar still includes many unwanted dependencies (some of which are those I've tried avoiding from being included)